# Wordpress Site says Front Page is 404 When Not Login

Tags: 404-error, frontpage

I have a Wordpress site, I have the Front Page settings right in the Reading settings, but when I goto my Wordpress site and I am not login, I get a 404 error and my page looks messed up. When I am login to Wordpress my Front Page looks like it should and I dont get a 404 page. Here is my site, why is this happening?

makinghermrs.com

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Also I am unable to change the static front page in my settings, when I save it, nothing gets changed.

More information in another question I asked:

[Issue with my theme](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/295005/issue-with-my-theme)

Comment: are you using any cache plugin??, If yes disable it and try again after clearing cache.

Comment: your site working fine now i have checked just display title wrong. Please check in private tab & change permalink one time first

Comment: Your theme or a plugin might be trying to redirect non-logged-in users to a page that doesn't exist. Try changing to a different theme to see if it stops doing that. If not, try disabling your plugins one at a time until it stops. You'll then know which one is causing the problem and can ask the developer of that plugin how to solve the problem.

Comment: I did have a cacheing plugin, It was disabled, I enabled and then disabled it and it worked.

Comment: I spoke too soon, the problem still exists. I think the problem is in my theme because when I switch to Twenty Seventeen it works! I dont get a 404 anymore, but when I switch it back to my theme, 404 problem is there

Comment: Looks like any of your plugin causing this issue, try disabling plugin one by one so that you can find the culprit. If you haven't tried it so far.

Comment: I have disabled all plugins one by one and I still had the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem, I found this code in my theme functions.php file:

```
function switch_homepage() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $page = 738; // for logged in users
        update_option( 'page_on_front', $page );
        update_option( 'show_on_front', 'page' );
    } else {
        $page = 738; // for logged out users
        update_option( 'page_on_front', $page );
        update_option( 'show_on_front', 'page' );
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'switch_homepage' );
```

So I remove it and now everything is working

Answer (score 0):

i think problem is in your composer. try disable your composer and check if it is working.
if not then try disable all your plugins one by one. if you are using cache disable it first.

Comment: Hello, how do I disable my composer?

Comment: I have also disabled all plugins one by one....did not work

Comment: which theme you are using? and what composer it that?

Comment: The theme is called Wedding Planner, the developer before me was using and we are currently using the child version. WPBakery Page Builder is the composer?

Comment: might be this is your theme. https://themeforest.net/item/wedding-planner-responsive-wedding-theme/19473925 check your theme version and latest version which is available and same for the visual composer version. might be this is the issue. one more question when you created you child theme? is not child theme issue? have you called style correctly ?

Comment: Yes that is the theme.....I am using version 1.6...I did not created the child theme, the previous developer did and hes not cooperating

Comment: as you can see the latest version is available on themeforest. if your client have purchase this theme, update it.

Comment: the client does not have that information, is there another way to get it from themeforest like an online chat?

Comment: there is no other way to get it, but nulled theme. that will be harmful for you server. first make sure that problem is in your theme or plugin. try to figure out this first. then resolve it

Comment: The problem is the theme...when I switch it to Twenty Seveteen, I dont get the 404 anymore

Comment: try enable the debug define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );
problem seems in your server then. can you check to install a new wordpress or transfer the same code somemhere else

Comment: I turned it on and got this: Notice: Use of undefined constant php - assumed 'php' in /home/makinghe/public_html/wp-content/themes/wedding-planner/include/primary-menu.php on line 9

Comment: This is line 9 <p class="content-font"><?php esc_html_e('SEARCH SITE BY TYPING (ESC TO CLOSE)', 'wedding-planner') ?></p>

Comment: Actually it was just this <?php ?> still didn't solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Make permalink structure to default `?p=ID` to ensure .htaccess is the problem.

Try simply set "month and name" structure again, and see if it works.

or Try [rewrite analyzer](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/)

**I'm Not Promoting the plugin** but it will help you.

Comment: I have tried playing with my permalink and nothing :( the problem still remains. I'll try the plugin.

Comment: How do I use this plugin? What am I looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to make a comment. Looking at your theme from themeforest. You stated that you had 1.6 loaded and the change log on themeforest states
Version 1.8 (27 January 2018)
- Various fixes & improvements (version 1.7 users, please deactivate & delete Visual Composer and install the one in version 1.8)

This is what I would do first. Update the theme and like suggested before switch out the Visual composer with the new one. I would also try turning off the Child theme just in case something broke there.

Comment: The old developer purchased the theme, the clients do not have access to theme forest creds

Comment: just buy a license for it from theme forest that way you have not only the latest version but access to the theme developers support.